# Add class to element whose id matches the class of another element

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop

I want to take the second class of an element, and then add a class to the element that has that ID. In Chrome, Firefox, etc. it works perfectly but in IE11 it does not. Do you know why? Help me please

```
for (var i = 0; i < $('#example .item').length; i++) {
  var class_svg = document.getElementsByClassName("item")[i].className.split(' ')[1];
  var $elem = document.getElementById(class_svg);  
  $elem.classList.add("show");
}
```

Comment: Check the console in IE11 and it will most likely be giving you an error which you can use to debug.

Comment: IE11 only has partial support of the `classList` API, and since I'm seeing `class_svg`, I'm thinking that it's because of this: "Does not have support for classList on SVG or MathML elements."

Answer (score 0):

According to [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) `classList` is only partially supported before Edge. Use `className` instead like:

```
$elem.className += ' show';
```

edit: thanks for the hint @Sterling Archer

Comment: Note that it's partially supported, not 'not supported' at all

Answer (score 0):

Creating a basic example using an SVG element (which I assume you have based on your example code) and looking at it in IE11 and Edge, you can see that the `className` property is a `[object SVGAnimatedString]`.  That is some special object for SVG elements, instead of dealing with that special object, lets just deal with the attribute itself using `getAttribute`.  Here is the code that works in most all browsers:

```
for (var i = 0; i < $('#example .item').length; i++) {
  var class_svg = document.getElementsByClassName("item")[i].getAttribute("class").split(' ')[1];
  var $elem = document.getElementById(class_svg); 
  var classList = $elem.getAttribute("class");
  classList += " show";
  $elem.setAttribute("class",classList);
}
```

Hope that works for you.